# Where to put bloc providers in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

I have tried to use bloc in flutter for a period, but the question of where to put bloc provider confuse me.

At the beginning of learning flutter, I put nearly all the providers in the main() function by using MultipleBlocProvider.

[image]

But due to some of my blocs subscribe to streams such as firebase snapshots, I think it might cost extra resources (I am not sure but at least some memory was occupied I guess) if I do not close those subscriptions by closing the bloc.

However, if the provider is in the main(), change page or pop up would not close these blocs and the subscriptions inside.

[image]

In this scenario, I try to put some bloc providers into specific pages, so the bloc can be close and recreate when I goes in and out of this page. But there are some other questions occurs.

For example, if I have a bloc called **ProductDetailsBloc** which is used to control the widget of product details in **product details page**, its events contains an event called **GetProductBySku** which is used to get product from firebase and set the product inside the state(**ProductDetailsState**).

I want to put this bloc and its provider inside **product details page** and put an event trigger inside **product list widget** (located in **product list page**) and its **onTap()** function, where users click on the **product list item** (this is a thumbnail product item which is from another resources and only contains very basic info such as sku, title ) inside **product list page** and then navigator to **product details page** to view the full information of this product.

But as I mentioned before, If I put the bloc provider of **ProductDetailsBloc** inside **product details page**, I can not use **GetProductBySku** before entering **product details page**

[image]

So, I personally have two ideas for this questions,

- the first one is passing the product sku through arguments to **product details page** and then call the **GetProductBySku** after the bloc has been created.
- the second one is the put the **ProductDetailsBloc** inside the main(), so I can skip this questions, and directly use the **GetProductBySku** in **product list widget**, but this turns the problems in to the very front.

I do not know which one is better, so I would be very appreciative if someone can give some suggestions.

And back to the main questions, what is the best practice of putting bloc providers and what are the concerns if I put providers inside main().

Thanks for every one that read to here because this is a bit long and this is my first time of asking on attack overflow :3

Answer (score 0):

You can find more discussion regarding this in the discord server of Bloc. More info: https://discord.com/channels/649708778631200778/649708993773699083/860604230930006016

> I will copy paste the message and code here. we have been using bloc
> in our app for over a year and it seems we have got an issue.
> Scenario: List of Posts needs to be shown in home feed. Let's say each
> post is encapsulated in PostBloc (operations on post to be performed
> here). I have been using moor to reactively find if anything changes
> in the data (like number of likes of post which might have trigged
> from post detail page where post detail was fetched again). I want to
> know if it is a wise decision to create BlocFactory which will be
> providing Bloc object (here different PostBloc object) based on
> Post_Id.
>
> I have written a sample BlocFactoryProvider, please let me know your
> thoughts

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:provider/single_child_widget.dart';

typedef CreateIfAbsent<T> = T Function();

//create bloc of <T> type
//author: https://github.com/imrhk
class BlocFactory<T extends Bloc<dynamic, dynamic>> {
  Map<String, T> _cache = <String, T>{};

  T createBloc({@required String id, @required CreateIfAbsent<T> createIfAbsent}) {
    assert(id != null && createIfAbsent != null);
    if (_cache.containsKey(id)) {
      return _cache[id];
    }
    final value = createIfAbsent.call();
    _cache[id] = value;
    return value;
  }

  void dispose() {
    _cache.values.forEach((bloc) => bloc?.close());
    _cache.clear();
  }
}

class BlocFactoryProvider<T extends Bloc<dynamic, dynamic>, V>
    extends SingleChildStatelessWidget {
  final BlocFactory<T> _blocFactory;
  final Widget child;
  BlocFactoryProvider({BlocFactory<T> blocFactory, this.child})
      : _blocFactory = blocFactory ?? BlocFactory<T>();
  @override
  Widget buildWithChild(BuildContext context, Widget child) {
    return InheritedProvider<BlocFactory<T>>(
      create: (_) => _blocFactory,
      dispose: (_, __) => _blocFactory.dispose(),
      child: child,
      lazy: false,
    );
  }

  static BlocFactory<T> of<T extends Bloc<dynamic, dynamic>>(BuildContext context) {
    try {
      return Provider.of<BlocFactory<T>>(context, listen: false);
    } on ProviderNotFoundException catch (e) {
      if (e.valueType != T) rethrow;
      throw FlutterError(
        """
        BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a Bloc of type $T.
        No ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to BlocProvider.of<$T>().

        This can happen if the context you used comes from a widget above the BlocProvider.

        The context used was: $context
        """,
      );
    }
}
```

Felix's replay was

> It’s hard to say without more context but I’d recommend moving the
> caching to the repository layer and instead have a single PostBloc
> with PostChanged event that pulls the latest details (using cache).
> So he did not completely discarded the idea.

declaration: I am the author of the below code shared over discord in March'21.